# Convert C# Datetime to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

DateTime field is 'not null' in Table Structure but I want to store data (MVC C# Datetime) 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to MySQL Table without changed table structure.

I Try to do this but its but ERROR!!

```
Convert.ToDateTime("0000/00/00");
```

Please HELP , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum value for .NET DateTime is January 1, 0001; the minimum for MySQL DATETIME is '1000-01-01', but in case of SQL MODE it is possible to insert '0000-00-00' as DATE, see NO_ZERO_DATE in documentation.

If you want to store '0000-00-00' in .NET DateTime structure, then use '0001-01-01', then if it is possible change this value in representation layer.

If you want to store '0000-00-00' in MySQL, then you should check SQL MODE in MySQL server -

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
  WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'sql_mode';
```

From documentation: NO_ZERO_DATE - In strict mode, do not permit '0000-00-00' as a valid date. You can still insert zero dates with the IGNORE option. When not in strict mode, the date is accepted but a warning is generated.

[Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Comment: +1 for `NO_ZERO_DATE - In strict mode, do not permit '0000-00-00' as a valid date`

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert those values as string

Like this

```
Create table tbl(dt datetime);
Insert into tbl values('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
SELECT CAST(dt as char) FROM tbl
```

## [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4eb855/2)

Comment: Thanks for help, have you give an example for WCF Data Service ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to create a C# DateTime object with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 - you can't, it's an invalid date. You could use [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue) though. From memory that's 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Why not use NULL?  Using magic values instead of NULL is not always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for make me aware that it can not do this :)